# Must declare the scalar variable "@vendor"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqldatasource, scalar, controlparameter

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IS315Database1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Category.CategoryName, Product.ProductName, Product.ProductPrice, Product.ProductID, vendor.VendorID, vendor.VendorName FROM vendor INNER JOIN Product ON vendor.VendorID = Product.VendorID INNER JOIN Category ON Product.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID WHERE ([VendorID] = @vendor.VendorID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="VendorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So I'm nearly 100% my error is coming from the end of the first line of code "WHERE ([VendorID] = @vendor.VendorID)">
        "

Does anyone know how to fix this, I've seen a couple of the same questions involving scalars, none have fixed or I haven't been able to throw my situation in the same context. Thank you.

Comment: Did you declare `@vendor`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, vendor is my vendor table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue is caused by lack of `@vendor` parameter declaration, as Juan Carlos Oropeza suggested in his comment. You rejected his suggestion, but after analysing the code I got into the same conclusion, so I decided to post more explanatory answer.

You used `@vendor` parameter in the query, but declared only `@VendorID` parameter (unless You declare other parameters somewhere else).

When You declare `ControlParameter`, the `Name` property indicates the name of parameter used in the query. In the code You posted, the parameter is named `VendorID`, so this name should be used in the query as well (with an additional `@` character that indicates it's a parameter's name).

Try to change the end of the query to `WHERE [VendorID] = @VendorID`.

For more information, take a look at:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx